# MySQL: AVG of defined variable per month

Tags: mysql

I need help with the following code:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
    userid
    , count( userid ) as login_count
FROM 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            userid
            , date(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_time)) AS DAY
        FROM xcart_login_history
        WHERE status="success" 
            and (action ="login" or action = "autologin") 
        ORDER BY userid, DAY
    ) as login_days
WHERE login_days.DAY < 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT min(date(FROM_UNIXTIME(xcart_orders.date)))
        FROM xcart_orders
        WHERE xcart_orders.userid = login_days.userid
        GROUP BY userid
    )
GROUP BY userid;
```

This shows me the `COUNT` of logins for individual users before purchasing. It is on purpose not returning more than one per day counted.

I now need the average login number / login count before purchase on a monthly basis.

For instance, the calculation should analyze the buys in January and calculate the average logins (max 1 per day) that were necessary for this purchase.

Could please somebody help me?

Comment: @Jean-Rémy As this seems more focused on the SQL language and less on database design, management, administration, etc, I would think this is the better place.

Comment: I'm not clear on exactly what you need.  Can you illustrate with some sample data and desired output?

Comment: Thank you guys for your help.

Let me try to explain:
I want to find the average number of logins a customer has executed before actually buying something.

Here an example of a row in the xcart_login_history:
userid=1 ; date_time=1304006969; action=login; status=success


Here an example of a row in the xcart_orders:
userid=1 ; date=1329855906;

These are actually all of the relevant information (dates are all UNIXTIME).

What I want to see as an endresult:
Month=January ; AVG_logins_before_buy= 17
Month=February ; AVG_logins_before_buy= 14
and so on.

Comment: Huh, is the policy now to move any SQL-related questions to DBA if they're not answered on SO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewritten to only count logins after the last previous order:

```
-- Calculate the previous order date for each order
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Orders
(
OrderID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
UserID  INT NOT NULL,
OrderDate   DATETIME NOT NULL,
Year    YEAR NOT NULL,
Month   TINYINT NOT NULL,
PreviousOrderDate   DATETIME
)
INSERT INTO Orders (OrderID, UserID, OrderDate, Year, Month, PreviousOrderDate)
    SELECT
        O2.orderid,
        O2.userid,
        FROM_UNIXTIME(O2.date) AS OrderDate,
        YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(O2.date)) AS Year,
        MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(O2.date)) AS Month,
        MAX(O1.date_time) AS PreviousOrderDate
    FROM
        xcart_orders AS O2
        LEFT JOIN xcart_orders AS O1 ON O2.userid = O1.userid AND O1.date_time < O2.date_time
    GROUP BY
        O2.orderid,
        O2.userid,
        O2.date

-- Calculate the average for each year and month
SELECT
    Year, Month, COUNT(*) AS Orders, SUM(PreviousLogins) / COUNT(*) AS AvgPrevLogins
FROM
    (
    -- Get the number of previous logins for each order
    SELECT
        O.OrderID, O.Year, O.Month, COUNT(L.userid) AS PreviousLogins
    FROM
        Orders AS O
        LEFT JOIN xcart_login_history AS L
            ON  O.UserID = L.userid
            -- Filter logins here in the join rather than in a WHERE clause, or you exclude orders that HAVE no previous logins (in practice, such may not exist)
            AND L.date < O.OrderDate
            AND (L.date > O.PreviousOrderDate OR O.PreviousOrderDate IS NULL)  -- Only count logins from after the last previous order (if one exists)
            AND L.status = 'success'
            AND L.action IN ('login', 'autologin')
    GROUP BY
        O.OrderID, O.Year, O.Month
    ) AS X
GROUP BY
    Year, Month
ORDER BY
    Year, Month
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64594/discussion-on-answer-by-jon-of-all-trades-mysql-avg-of-defined-variable-per-mon).